# android studio compare date child from firebase with date device

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

How can I compare the day and month that the user registered when registering with the day and month (firebase child: Cumpleaños) of the device used? this is what i tried

[image: firebase database child Cumpleaños: 08-Nov]

```
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       CumpleañosRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(CurrentUserID);
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

       final SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM", Locale.getDefault());
       saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());
       CumpleañosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               if (dataSnapshot.child("Cumpleaños").equals(currentDate))
               {
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dd89d7"));
               }
               else
               {
                   relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });
   }
```

need that when the dates of firebase child and device coincide (day and month) change the color of the background.  Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the code that you have shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the value of your child by calling `getValue()` (check for null to avoid NullPointerExceptions)

```
String dateAsStringFromDB = dataSnapshot.child("Cumpleaños").getValue();
```

After you got the String value ("09-Nov" for example) `currentDate` to parse the dates

```
Date realtimeDate = currentDate.parse(saveCurrentDate);
Date dateFromDB = currentDate.parse(dateAsStringFromDB);
```

Then comparing the dates using `compareTo()` method

```
if(realtimeDate.compareTo(dateFromDB) == 0 ){
 // do stuff .. 

 }
```

**Don't forget to avoid null pointer and cast exceptions**

Comment: `String dateAsStringFromDB = dataSnapshot.child ("Cumpleaños"). GetValue ();` it says needs to be String

and the 2 Date needs to be used the try / catch

I have done them and it does not work

Comment: Does the parse to date succeeded ? in you try/catch block . and if it does when you log the dates what do you see?

Comment: the logcat says that it successfully connected to the timestamp, but nothing about  parse  or  dates

Comment: if you still having trouble with it you can post a screenshot of your code and ill look at it :)

Comment: I found the problem, what you told me is correct, the datepicker tells me the date wrong thx